# Java automatic modules with Maven

Tags: java, maven, java-9, module-info

Software versions:

Apache Maven 3.5.3
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.5.3
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation

I have Maven dependency when I run `mvn compile` command in terminal it gives me this error:

```
java/module-info.java:[6,32] module not found: org.apache.logging.log4j
```

This jar is already in my Maven repository. I know these are automatic modules but I do not know how to take care of this problem. I tried a few ways which I found on the web but did not work out.

Comment: Can you show your full pom file...

Comment: Try temporary removing the descriptor and run `mvn compile org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:list -DincludeScope=compile` with Java9+

Comment: If you're using a recent version of Log4J (e.g. 2.11), then you're not dealing with an automatic module - it contains a proper module descriptor (it's a [multi-release JAR](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/), so it's in `META-INF/releases/9`). If you're using a version without a descriptor or an automatic module name, the name would likely be _log4j.api_, not _org.apache.logging.log4j_.